# TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') for Twitter bot

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
// function to generate a random tweet tweet
function ranDom (arr) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
  return arr[index];
};
```

This is the code used

Comment: What is the value of `arr`? It's certainly not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here:

```js
function ranDom (arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
};

var items = [254, 45, 212, 365, 2543];
console.log(ranDom(items));
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can add this line in the start of your function

```
if (arr === undefined){
    return DEFAULT_VALUE; \\define your default value for this case..
}
```

to handle this case.

But you need to investigate why your arr is undefined from the function call.